# How to pass form data from php processing page to success page?

Tags: php

I would like to know how to pass form data from a php processing page to a success page.

How can I pass the $orderid to my success page? I only need to pass this one value so something simple would be great! :-P

```
<?php

$stamp = date("Ymdhis");
$random_id_length = 6;
$rndid = generateRandomString( $random_id_length );

$orderid = $stamp ."-". $rndid;

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789';
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
$randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}

$repairtitle = $_POST['courierrepairtitle'];
$repairconsole = $_POST['courierrepairconsole'];
$repairprice = $_POST['courierrepairprice'];
$outwardpostage = $_POST['outwardpostage'];
$returnpostage = $_POST['returnpostage'];
$name = $_POST['couriername'];
$email = $_POST['courieremail'];
$homephone = $_POST['courierhomephone'];
$mobilephone = $_POST['couriermobilephone'];
$address1 = $_POST['courieraddress1'];
$address2 = $_POST['courieraddress2'];
$address3 = $_POST['courieraddress3'];
$city = $_POST['couriercity'];
$county = $_POST['couriercounty'];
$postcode = $_POST['courierpostcode'];
$country = $_POST['couriercountry'];
$formcontent=" Order No: $orderid \n \n Repair Title: $repairtitle \n Console: $repairconsole \n Price: $repairprice \n \n Outward Postage: $outwardpostage \n Return Postage: $returnpostage \n \n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Home Phone: $homephone \n Mobile Phone: $mobilephone \n \n Address1: $address1 \n Address2: $address2 \n Address3: $address3 \n City: $city \n County: $county \n Postcode: $postcode \n Country: $country ";
$recipient = "info@example.co.uk";
$subject = "Order Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
// Test to see if variables are empty:
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($homephone) && !empty($address1) && !empty($city) && !empty($postcode) && !empty($country)){
// Test to see if the mail sends successfully:
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
    header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk/courier-mailer-success.htm");
}else{
    header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk/courier-mailer-fail.htm");
}
}else{
header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk/courier-mailer-fail.htm");
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: why not as a parameter

Answer (score 5):

You could place it at the end of the URL as a GET parameter.

```
'success.php?orderid=one'
```

on that page access it with:

```
 $_GET['item']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could Store your data in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and access it from your success page

Comment: Could you expand on this with an example modifying the question's code?

Answer (score 0):

A [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variable would work great in this case. These are used to persist data between pages, and this gives the benefit of being able to access this variable throughout your application without having to pass as a GET parameter for every page where necessary.  At the very top of your file, you'll need to start your session:

```
<?php

session_start();

$stamp = date("Ymdhis");
...
```

From here, you now have access to assign a session variable. the code will be as follows:

```
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
    $_SESSION['orderid'] = $orderid;
    header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk/courier-mailer-success.htm");
}
```

From here, redirect to your success page. **You will need to make your courier-mailer-success.htm into a .php file in order to access this data**. You'll also need to add `session_start();` to the top of your success page to access the session data. You can access your variable like so:

```
<?php

session_start();

...

$id = $_SESSION['orderid'];
echo $id;
```